# the fastest method of capturing full screen with python?

Tags: python, imagegrab

I was using ImageGrab from PIL, but this is too slow to use for the project.

Are there any alternatives without using PIL?

Comment: The answer is likely to differ according to the OS you use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capturing an image is equivalent to capture a single frame of a video. You can do it using the VideoCapture method of OpenCV.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # video capture source camera (Here webcam of laptop) 
ret,frame = cap.read() # return a single frame in variable `frame`

while(True):
    cv2.imshow('img',frame) #display the captured image
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('y'): #save on pressing 'y' 
        cv2.imwrite('images/test.png',frame)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

cap.release()
```

Check the [OpenCV](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) tutorial for more information.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks